# What factory (UniswapV2Factory) shoud I use when deploy Sushiswap clone?

Tags: contract-deployment, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment, uniswap, defi

Hi I'm forking Sushiswap and about to deploy contract to mainnet.

While I'm writing deploy_contract.js in Truffle.

Which Factory shoud I use in my migration code? I saw several code example but somebody just use Uniswap Factory address in Mainnet and somebody use their own UniswapV2Factory. Which one shoud I use at mainnet?

And If you have some migration code(deploy_contract.js) example for Sushiswap or Uniswap. Please let me know about it.